# Is it a bad idea to define some, but not all methods of a type class in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Want to do this:

```
data Point = Point Double Double

instance Num Point where
      (Point ax ay) + (Point bx by) = Point (ax + bx) (ay + by)
      negate (Point ax ay) = Point (negate ax) (negate ay)
```

Syntastic doesn't like it. Wants me to define methods for `*`, `abs`, `fromInteger` and `signum`.

What's a recommended way to get me a `+` and `-` operator defined for Point without taking on the rest?

Also, I could define some different kinds of scalar and vector multiplication like `Double * Point` or `Point * Point` in a cross-product or dot-product sense. But the type system isn't my friend here, right?

Comment: well, in most programming languages, you cannot add or subtract two different objects, so I think you may have to define methods

Comment: The minimal definition for `Num` requires (+), (*), abs, signum, fromInteger and negate/-. If you can't implement them all then your type isn't an instance of `Num`. You will have to use different operator names than `+` and `-`.

Comment: This is a common complaint with the `Num` typeclass. Many libraries have been written factoring it into logical building blocks with mathematical foundations: Monoid -> Group -> Ring -> Field. Your `Point`, for example, is almost a Group. You just need to define `zero = Point 0 0` which is the identity of your `+` operation defined on `Point`

Comment: You can specify `undefined` as the implementation for the Num instance functions you don't want (i.e. `abs = undefined`), but you'll have to be careful to never pass your points to functions that use those values or you'll get runtime errors that crash your program. That's why it's considered bad form.

Answer (score 4):

And `+` is the only operator you can think of? Why not `+/`? Or `+.`? What's wrong with them?

Yes, leaving members of class unimplemented is Bad Form.

As the last resort, you could define your own typeclass like this

```
import Prelude hiding ((+))
import qualified Prelude ((+))

class Plus c where (+) :: c -> c -> c
instance Plus Double where (+) = Prelude.(+)

instance Plus Point where Point x1 y1 + Point x2 y2 = Point (x1 + x2) (y1 + y2)
```

Comment: The notable exception is the `fail` member of `Monad`, which should never have been a member of that class at all. The `Num` and `Integral` classes are pretty shady, mathematically, but we can't really fix that.

Comment: @dfeuer That's not really an exception, since `fail` has a default implementation.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, you're right about that. Unfortunately, the only thing to do about it is to be very careful not to use it by mistake.

Answer (score 4):

The type system doesn't help here because `Num` isn't an appropriate type class for 2 dimensional points. From what you describe, you want to have a 2-dimensional vector space over `Double`s.

I'd suggest you to have a look at [Linear.V2](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.10.1.1/docs/Linear-V2.html). It provides abstraction of vector spaces, with finely grained hierarchy of type classes. In particular, the vector space part is captured by [`Additive`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.10.1.1/docs/Linear-Vector.html#t%3aAdditive) and the dot product by [`Metric`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.10.1.1/docs/Linear-Metric.html#t%3aMetric). Of course, you could also take your definition of `Point` and just implement these type classes.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say this has a two-sided answer:

1. It is definitely bad form not to define some of the methods of a class.  I'd recommend not to do it.
2. Many people agree that Haskell's numeric class hierarchy is a wart.  But the problem is that it's very difficult to design a proposal that everybody will agree to; you have to find a consensus balance between "very flexible" and "it takes a Math degree to add two `Integers`."

So you get things like [the `numeric-prelude` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude), but not widespread adoption.

However, if what you really care for is to be able to use the `+` and `-` as syntax, Haskell does not force you to use the default implementations; you can "opt out" of any of the default things in the `Prelude` library, like this:

```
module MyModule where

import Prelude hiding ((+), (-))
import qualified Prelude as P

class MyNum a where
    (+) :: a -> a -> a
    negate :: a -> a

    (-) :: a -> a -> a
    a - b = a + negate b


data Point = ...

instance MyNum Point where
    a + b = ...
    negate a = ...

-- Convenience instances for regular numeric types, so that you can write
-- things like `5 + 7` as well.
instance MyNum Integer where
    a + b = a P.+ b
    ...
```

In every module where you import this `MyModule` you have to have the `import Prelude hiding ((+), (-))` in order to hide the default `Num` implementations.

The downside to this is of course that this is highly unexpected for people reading your code.